# Get intermediate color from a gradient

Tags: c++, qt, colors, gradient, linear-gradients

Say I have a liner gradient as shown:

```
QLinearGradient linearGrad(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(0, 100));
linearGrad.setColorAt(1, Qt::red);
linearGrad.setColorAt(0.5, Qt::yellow);
linearGrad.setColorAt(0, Qt::green);
```

How to get the color of the point QPointF(0, 28.5) in this gradient?

Indeed I want to have this kind of color distribution to be able to choose intermediate colors. I don't care if it is done by using QLinearGradient or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only way to make it:

There is a static member in QPixmap class
`QPixmap QPixmap::grabWindow( WId window, int x = 0, int y = 0, int width = -1, int height = -1 )`

1) draw your gradient on your widget;

2) grab you widget's surface into pixmap using that function; `WId` can be received from `QWidget::effectiveWinId ()`;

3) convert token pixmap into `QImage` (there is an constructor available);

4) `int QImage::pixelIndex( int x, int y )` returns the pixel index at (x, y) in `QImage`'s color table. In your case you must calculate percentage value from widget's height ( `pWidget->height() / 100 * 28.5` ).

5) `QRgb QImage::color( int i )` returns the color in the color table at index i.

So returned Color is the color you were seeking.

Answer (score 11):

I store the colors of gradient in one QList and then compute with color interpolation.

```
QColor ColorGradient::getColor(double value)
{
  qDebug()<< "ColorGradient::getColor:";
    //Asume mGradientColors.count()>1 and value=[0,1]
    double stepbase = 1.0/(mGradientColors.count()-1);
    int interval=mGradientColors.count()-1; //to fix 1<=0.99999999;

      for (int i=1; i<mGradientColors.count();i++)//remove begin and end
        {
            if(value<=i*stepbase ){interval=i;break;}
        }
       double percentage = (value-stepbase*(interval-1))/stepbase;
       QColor color(interpolate(mGradientColors[interval],mGradientColors[interval-1],percentage));        
       return color;
}
QColor ColorGradient::interpolate(QColor start,QColor end,double ratio)
{
    int r = (int)(ratio*start.red() + (1-ratio)*end.red());
    int g = (int)(ratio*start.green() + (1-ratio)*end.green());
    int b = (int)(ratio*start.blue() + (1-ratio)*end.blue());
    return QColor::fromRgb(r,g,b);
}
```

Comment: Since this is an old answered question. Why this is the best question and that can help OP's question? Please, avoid to post an question that has accepted answer.

Comment: I think this is a good answer.  For others searching like myself, I find it much more helpful than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Mason Zhang answer does work, and very well !
Let controlPoints() return a `QMap<qreal,QColor>`, with a key between 0.0 and 1.0.
Here is how i did (thanks to Mason Zhang)

```
QColor getColor(qreal key) const
{
    // key must belong to [0,1]
    key = Clip(key, 0.0, 1.0) ;

    // directly get color if known
    if(controlPoints().contains(key))
    {
        return controlPoints().value(key) ;
    }

    // else, emulate a linear gradient
    QPropertyAnimation interpolator ;
    const qreal granularite = 100.0 ;
    interpolator.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear) ;
    interpolator.setDuration(granularite) ;
    foreach( qreal key, controlPoints().keys() )
    {
        interpolator.setKeyValueAt(key, controlPoints().value(key)) ;
    }
    interpolator.setCurrentTime(key*granularite) ;
    return interpolator.currentValue().value<QColor>() ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QVariantAnimation has the similar functionality, and QVariantAnimation::keyValueAt can return the value you need. You may step into the code of QVariantAnimation and see how keyValueAt works.

Comment: I have no idea how to use QVariantAnimation abstract class. Please, if you have en example, demonstrate it.

Comment: just use functions below as what you have done by QLinearGradient:
- QVariantAnimation::setStartValue ( const QVariant & value )
- QVariantAnimation::setKeyValueAt( qreal step, const QVariant & value );
- QVariantAnimation::setEndValue ( const QVariant & value );

Then get the the value at a point by 
- QVariantAnimation::keyValueAt ( qreal step );

The issue here is, QVariantAnimation does not support QColor. I'm not sure if converting QColor to Int works or not.

Comment: QVariantAnimation is an abstract class. It should be inherited and implemented.

Comment: why not try the concrete class "QPropertyAnimation"?